# Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR with Numba guVectorize tags

Tags: python, gpu, numba

Im trying to get a python bilateral filter I wrote to work on my GPU but I keep running into errors and I got one that's very cryptic to me. When I run the code I get

```
Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

Based on other posts it seems to be something with memory issues? But since Im not writing my code in cuda or messing with the memory(Im just adding the tags to get it run on GPU) Im not sure what the best approach is going to be to fix this. Am I converting the code to run on GPU incorrectly?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import math
import cmath
import tqdm
from numba import jit, cuda, vectorize, guvectorize, float64, int64

sIntesity = 12.0
sSpace = 16.0
diameter = 100

@guvectorize([(float64[:,:], float64[:,:])],  '(n,m)->(n,m)',target='cuda',nopython =True)
def apply_filter(img, filteredImage):

    #imh, imw = img.shape[:2]
    imh = 600
    imw = 600
    hd = int((diameter - 1) / 2)

    for h in range(hd, imh - hd):
        for w in range(hd, imw - hd):
            Wp = 0
            filteredPixel = 0
            radius = diameter // 2
            for x in range(0, diameter):
                for y in range(0, diameter):

                    currentX = w - (radius - x)
                    cureentY = h - (radius - y)

                    intensityDifferent = img[currentX][cureentY] - img[w][h]
                    intensity = (1.0/ (2 * math.pi * (sIntesity ** 2))* math.exp(-(intensityDifferent ** 2) / (2 * sIntesity ** 2)))
                    foo = (currentX - w) ** 2 + (cureentY - h) ** 2
                    distance = cmath.sqrt(foo)
                    smoothing = (1.0 / (2 * math.pi * (sSpace ** 2))) * math.exp( -(distance.real ** 2) / (2 * sSpace ** 2))
                    weight = intensity * smoothing
                    filteredPixel += img[currentX][cureentY] * weight
                    Wp += weight

            filteredImage[h][w] = int(round(filteredPixel / Wp))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = cv2.imread("messy2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    src = src.astype(float)
    filtered_image_own = np.zeros(src.shape)
    print(type(src),type(filtered_image_own))
    apply_filter(src, filtered_image_own)
    filtered_image_own = filtered_image_own.astype(np.uint8) 
    cv2.imwrite("filtered_image4.png", filtered_image_own)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could include a minimal, complete example. It looks like you could make an example without using openCV and by showing an example array of data.

Comment: Somehow getting rid of cv2 gets rid of the problem? But it runs way too slow and not on the GPU then. I have no clue how that's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching it from CUDA to cpu allowed me to see that there was a bug in the code and it was attempting to get a invalid index, that error was just the way it was telling me something was wrong

Comment: To clarify, switching to CPU with `@guvectorize` means `@guvectorize([(float64[:,:], float64[:,:])],  '(n,m)->(n,m)',target='cpu',nopython =True)` instead of `...,target='cuda'`

Comment: If you're using `cuda.jit` instead of `guvectorize`, a simple swap can be performed using Numba's [CUDA Simulator](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/simulator.html) via `import os; os.environ["NUMBA_ENABLE_CUDASIM"] = "1"; os.environ["NUMBA_CUDA_DEBUGINFO"] = "1";` **preceding** the `from numba import ...` statement. Swap both back to `"0"` when finished debugging. See [68859699/13697228](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68859699/13697228) for a tutorial on how to do this in Spyder with pdb.