# Numba code compilation for CUDA GPU fails with OSError: exception: access violation reading

Tags: python, gpu, numba

I stumbled across a problem when writing some code in Python/Numba for CUDA GPU and I simply don't d know what I am doing wrong or which component is bad. In 95% percent of the cases the program is not compiled, since I receive the following error when I restart the python kernel and try to run the CUDA kernel written by me.

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
6 data_isgomoku = np.load("data/isgomoku_moreThan5Good.npy")
7
----> 8 kernel_test_02[blocks, threads_per_block](envs_in_gpu, envs_out_gpu, random_states, data_isgomoku, proximities)
9 print ("Run OKAY")

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in call(self, *args)
757 '''
758 #print ("_call *args=",*args)
--> 759 kernel = self.specialize(*args)
760 cfg = kernel[self.griddim, self.blockdim, self.stream, self.sharedmem]
761 cfg(*args)

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in specialize(self, *args)
768 argtypes = tuple(
769 [self.typingctx.resolve_argument_type(a) for a in args])
--> 770 kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
771 return kernel
772

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in compile(self, sig)
787 self.definitions[(cc, argtypes)] = kernel
788 if self.bind:
--> 789 kernel.bind()
790 return kernel
791

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in bind(self)
528 Force binding to current CUDA context
529 """
--> 530 self._func.get()
531
532 @Property

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in get(self)
405 cufunc = self.cache.get(device.id)
406 if cufunc is None:
--> 407 ptx = self.ptx.get()
408
409 # Link

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\compiler.py in get(self)
376 arch = nvvm.get_arch_option(*cc)
377 ptx = nvvm.llvm_to_ptx(self.llvmir, opt=3, arch=arch,
--> 378 **self._extra_options)
379 self.cache[cc] = ptx
380 if config.DUMP_ASSEMBLY:

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\nvvm.py in llvm_to_ptx(llvmir, **opts)
498 cu.add_module(libdevice.get())
499
--> 500 ptx = cu.compile(**opts)
501 # XXX remove debug_pubnames seems to be necessary sometimes
502 return patch_ptx_debug_pubnames(ptx)

~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\nvvm.py in compile(self, **options)
234 c_opts = (c_char_p * len(opts))(*[c_char_p(x.encode('utf8'))
235 for x in opts])
--> 236 err = self.driver.nvvmCompileProgram(self._handle, len(opts), c_opts)
237 self._try_error(err, 'Failed to compile\n')
238

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000001C3B042FFF8
```

As far I can see this is clearly a problem with the code sent to the NVVM compiler, because it crashes it. I tried it out with CUDA Toolkit 9.2, 10.0,10.1,10.2 and various versions of Numba, but the problem persists in all cases.

Could someone having already installed Numba, NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit, Jupyter Notebook please check out the code and files available at [sample code to reproduce the error](https://gitlab.com/pittnerf1/test-project-for-numba-and-cuda-functions/-/tree/master) if the problem can be reproduced or not?

Does anyone have any hint what I am doing wrong?

In order to reproduce this on Windows try a few times to: a. restart your python kernel and b. try to run it. Code:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import os 
import sys
import pickle
import random
import numba 
from numba import jit,cuda
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states, xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32

# constants
MOVE_E = 0
MOVE_X = 1
MOVE_O = 2
MOVE_I = 3
# board representation
gb_type = np.dtype([
    ('boardO',(np.int32,29*29)),
    ('boardX',(np.int32,29*29)),
    ('boardCommon',(np.int32,29*29)),
    ('moveProximities',(np.int32,29*29)),
    ('noOfMoves', np.int32),
    ('undo_moveProximitites', np.int32, (19 * 19, 5*5)),
    ('undo_moves', np.int32, (19 * 19, 4)), # 0 - pos, 1-  lastMoveColor, posTypesX[movepos], posTypesO[movepos]
    ('doSaveUndoInformation', np.int32),
    ('lastMove', np.int32),
    ('lastMoveColor', np.int32),
    ('colorToMove', np.int32),
    ('gameEnded', np.int32),
    ('hashkey1', np.int32),
    ('hashkey2', np.int32),
    ('posTypesX',(np.int32,29*29)), # bitek: 0:gomoku, 1:D1, 2:D2, 3:A1, 4:A2, 5: W2, 6: A1xA2, 7: A2xA2, 8:A2 later A1
    ('posTypesO',(np.int32,29*29)),
    ('undo_movePosTypesX', np.int32, (19 * 19, 8*5)),
    ('undo_movePosTypesO', np.int32, (19 * 19, 8*5))
    ])

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def cuda_init(env, startFromCenter , startFromCentralHalf, proximities,  random_states):
    "init the board's data and calculate proximities"
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.boardO)
    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.boardX)
    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.moveProximities)
    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.boardCommon)
    env.noOfMoves = 0
    #env.undo_boardO[:,:] = 0
    #env.undo_boardX[:,:] = 0
    for i in range(19 * 19):
        for j in range(4):
            env.undo_moves[i,j] = 0
        for j in range(5*5):
            env.undo_moveProximitites[i,j] = 0

    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.posTypesX)
    cuda_fillArrayWithZero(env.posTypesO)

    if startFromCenter:
        gb_updateMoveProximities(env, gb_calcPosFromXY(9,9), proximities)
        env.moveProximities[gb_calcPosFromXY(9,9)] = 1
    elif startFromCentralHalf:
        X = 4+int(14 * xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(random_states, thread_id))
        Y = 4 + int(14 * xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(random_states, thread_id))
        #X = random.randint(4, 18 - 4)
        #Y = random.randint(4, 18 - 4)
        gb_updateMoveProximities(env, gb_calcPosFromXY(X, Y), proximities)
        env.moveProximities[gb_calcPosFromXY(X, Y)] = 1


    env.lastMove = -1
    env.lastMoveColor = 2
    env.colorToMove = 1
    env.doSaveUndoInformation = True
    env.gameEnded = False
    env.hashkey1 = 267425067
    env.hashkey2 = 576253428
    return

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def cuda_fillArrayWithZero(myarray):
    "fill array with zero"
    for i in range(myarray.shape[0]):
        myarray[i] = 0
    return

@cuda.jit("i4(i4,i4)",device=True)
def gb_calcPosFromXY( X, Y):
    "convert coordinates"
    if  not(X>=0 and X<19): print ("Error calcPosFromXY, wrong X=" ,X)
    if not(Y >= 0 and Y < 19): print("Error calcPosFromXY, wrong Y=" ,Y)
    return (5+X) + 29*(5+Y)

@cuda.jit( "UniTuple(i8, 2)(i4)",device=True)
def gb_calcXYFromPos( pos):
    "convert coordinates"
    if pos is None:
        return -1, -1
    if not(pos>=0 and pos < 29*29): print ( "Error calcXYFromPos, wrong pos number=" , pos)
    X = pos % 29 - 5
    Y = int (((pos - 5 - X) / 29)) - 5
    if not(X >= 0 and X < 19): print("Error calcXYFromPos, wrong X=", X)
    if not(Y >= 0 and Y < 19): print("Error calcXYFromPos, wrong Y=", Y)
    return X,Y


@cuda.jit(device=True)
def gb_updateMoveProximities(env, pos, proximities):
    "set some positions to 1 using the coordinates in the pre-calculated proximities array"
    if pos != -1:
        k=0
        while proximities[pos, k]>0:
            kPos = proximities[pos, k]
            #print (kPos, gb_calcXYFromPos(kPos))
            if env.boardCommon[kPos] == 0:
                env.moveProximities[kPos] = 1
            k += 1
    else:
        pos = gb_calcPosFromXY(9,9)
        k = 0
        while proximities[pos, k] > 0:
            kPos = proximities[pos, k]
            env.moveProximities[kPos] = 1
            k += 1
        env.moveProximities[pos] = 1


# CUDA kernel test 1 - init board

# define 100 boards
N=100
envs = np.zeros(N, dtype=gb_type)


threads_per_block = 64
# Calculate the number of thread blocks in the grid
blocks = (envs.shape[0] + (threads_per_block - 1)) // threads_per_block
print ("threads_per_block = ", threads_per_block, "blockspergrid=", blocks)
random_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=1)    

#kernel function
@cuda.jit()
def kernel_test_01(io_array, out_array, proximities, random_states):
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
    if thread_id < io_array.size:
        cuda_init(io_array[thread_id], True, False, proximities, random_states)
        out_array[thread_id] = io_array[thread_id]

#  test kernel 1
envs_out = np.zeros((envs.shape[0]), dtype = gb_type)
envs_in_gpu = numba.cuda.to_device(envs)
envs_out_gpu = numba.cuda.to_device(envs_out)
#proximities = np.load("data/proximities_2.npy")
proximities = np.zeros((841, 25), dtype=np.int32)

kernel_test_01[blocks, threads_per_block](envs_in_gpu, envs_out_gpu, proximities, random_states)
print ("Run OKAY")

# CUDA kernel test 2 - call some more device functions

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def gb_calc_gindex(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10):
    return int((((((((((((((((((i1 << 1) + i2) << 1) +
                         i3) << 1) + i4) << 1) + i5) << 1) +
                   i6) << 1) + i7) << 1) + i8) << 1) +
             i9) << 1) + i10)

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def isPosValid(pos):
    "check if a position is valid"
    i = pos % 29 - 5
    j = int (((pos - 5 - i) / 29)) - 5
    if i>=0 and i<19 and j>=0 and j<19:
        return True
    return False

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def gb_check_if_gomokuPos(env , POS, color, dontCheckPos , data_isgomoku):

    if not isPosValid(POS):
        X,Y = gb_calcXYFromPos(POS)
        print("Error gb_check_if_gomokuPos, wrong X or Y=", X, Y)

    # ha foglalt
    #if env.boardCommon[POS] != 0:
    #    return False

    if not dontCheckPos:
        if env.boardX[POS] != 0 or env.boardO[POS] != 0:
            return False

    board = env.boardX
    if color == MOVE_O:
        board = env.boardO

    if board[POS-1] == 1 or board[POS+1] == 1:
        index = gb_calc_gindex(board[POS-5],board[POS-4],board[POS-3],board[POS-2],board[POS-1],board[POS+1],board[POS+2],board[POS+3],board[POS+4],board[POS+5])
        if index <0 or index > data_isgomoku.shape[0]: print ("Error gb_check_if_gomokuPos, wrong index=", index, 1)

        if data_isgomoku[index]:
            return True

    if board[POS-29] == 1 or board[POS+29] == 1:
        index = gb_calc_gindex(board[POS-145],board[POS-116],board[POS-87],board[POS-58],board[POS-29],board[POS+29],board[POS+58],board[POS+87],board[POS+116],board[POS+145])
        if index < 0 or index > data_isgomoku.shape[0]: print("Error gb_check_if_gomokuPos, wrong index=", index, 2)

        if data_isgomoku[index]:
            return True

    if board[POS-30] == 1 or board[POS+30] == 1:
        index = gb_calc_gindex(board[POS-150],board[POS-120],board[POS-90],board[POS-60],board[POS-30],board[POS+30],board[POS+60],board[POS+90],board[POS+120],board[POS+150])
        if index < 0 or index > data_isgomoku.shape[0]: print("Error gb_check_if_gomokuPos, wrong index=", index, 3)

        if data_isgomoku[index]:
            return True

    if board[POS-28] == 1 or board[POS+28] == 1:
        index = gb_calc_gindex(board[POS-140],board[POS-112],board[POS-84],board[POS-56],board[POS-28],board[POS+28],board[POS+56],board[POS+84],board[POS+112],board[POS+140])
        if index < 0 or index > data_isgomoku.shape[0]: print("Error gb_check_if_gomokuPos, wrong index=", index, 4)

        if data_isgomoku[index]:
            return True


    return False

@cuda.jit()
def kernel_test_02(io_array, out_array, random_states, data_isgomoku,proximities):
    "this kernel serves only for testing purposes, it calls some of the device functions in order to check if they work properly"

    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
    if thread_id < io_array.size:

        X = 12 
        Y = 12 
        pos = gb_calcPosFromXY(X,Y)
        env = io_array[thread_id]
        # 
        cuda_init(io_array[thread_id], True, False, proximities, random_states)
        gb_updateMoveProximities(env, pos, proximities)
        v = gb_check_if_gomokuPos(env, pos, MOVE_X, False, data_isgomoku)

        out_array[thread_id] = io_array[thread_id]

#  test kernel 2
envs_out = np.zeros((envs.shape[0]), dtype = gb_type)
envs_in_gpu = numba.cuda.to_device(envs)
envs_out_gpu = numba.cuda.to_device(envs_out)
#proximities = np.load("data/proximities_2.npy")
proximities = np.zeros((841, 25), dtype=np.int32)
#data_isgomoku = np.load("data/isgomoku_moreThan5Good.npy")
data_isgomoku = np.zeros((1024), dtype=np.int32)

kernel_test_02[blocks, threads_per_block](envs_in_gpu, envs_out_gpu, random_states, data_isgomoku, proximities)
print ("Run OKAY")
```

Comment: Having code sitting at a the end of a link isn't very helpful. You should be able to post a repro case in the question.

Comment: It is not only code, there are two additional binary files, too. I also wanted to add, that I am running Numba on Windows 10  and not on Linux. This may be important.

Comment: The binaries are irrelevant. You either have code which blows up the Numba compiler or you don't. If you do, post that code **in your question**. Otherwise this is a waste of everyone's time, including yours

Comment: Okay, code added above.

Comment: I am 99.99999% sure Numba for the GPU doesn't support custom dtypes of any kind. I am not surprised it blows up the compiler

Comment: I have already developed software for GPU using Numba and custom dtypes. That one works fine.

Comment: This one clearly doesn't file a bug report with the Numba developers

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the custom ndtype and the access violation problem disappeared on numba 0.46. Unfortunately later versions seem to be unstable and still produce randomly "access violation" errors despite the fact that there is no custom ndtype used.

Comment: See my answer about using Cuda Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I also met with same issue.
The program can pass sometimes, however 95% the program will print out

> err = self.driver.nvvmCompileProgram(self._handle, len(opts), c_opts)
> OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000017CF7D14718

after some search, it related to the parameter passing in the CUDA function. Sometimes the function cannot convert the parameter type correctly. However the final solution still not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging with Cuda Simulator

Enabling [CUDA Simulator](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/simulator.html) can often help with debugging this type of error if it's a bug in the user code.

### More descript errors

```py
import os

# needs to appear before `from numba import cuda`
os.environ["NUMBA_ENABLE_CUDASIM"] = "1"
# set to "1" for more debugging, but slower performance
os.environ["NUMBA_CUDA_DEBUGINFO"] = "1"

from numba import cuda, njit
```

Instead of the non-descript access error, it goes into the (fake) kernel and produces a more meaningful error. In my case:

```py
  File "C:\Users\sterg\...\wasserstein-gpu-debug.py", line 372, in divide
    out[i] = v[i] / b
IndexError: tid=[1, 0, 0] ctaid=[0, 0, 0]: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

### Debugging with python debugger (pdb)

Even better, if I enter in debugging mode (Ctrl+F5 in Spyder 5.0.5) with the configuration per file (Ctrl+F6 or Menubar --> Run --> "Configuration per file...") set to "Execute in an external system console":

[image]

and "Interact with the Python console after execution":
[image]

then I can use `locals()` to verify that `v` is a 4-element 1D array, `b` is a scalar,`out` is a 3-element 1D array, and `i` is 3 (which comes from range(len(v)):

```py
(Pdb) locals()
{'v': array([0.        , 0.54269606, 0.8236306 , 1.1803839 ], dtype=float32), 'b': 1.1803839, 'out': array([0.        , 0.45976233, 0.697765  ], dtype=float32), 'i': 3}
```

Obviously `out[3] = v[3]` is going to produce an error here (as the `IndexError` message implied) when out only has 3 elements.

If this didn't help me, (and for those less familiar with pdb), I could then use `u` to go up in the stack trace, `d` to go down, and `w` to check where I am. ([pdb commands](https://web.stanford.edu/class/physics91si/2013/handouts/Pdb_Commands.pdf) and [pdb docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)).

### Finished debugging

When finished debugging, set the environment variables back to "0" so that your code can run quickly again.

```py
import os

# needs to appear before `from numba import cuda`
os.environ["NUMBA_ENABLE_CUDASIM"] = "0"
# set to "1" for more debugging, but slower performance
os.environ["NUMBA_CUDA_DEBUGINFO"] = "0"

from numba import cuda, njit
```

## `numba 0.55.0`/`cudatoolkit 11.2.2` --> OP code OK

As for the OP's use-case, I ran the code (without the `%` lines at the beginning) in a Spyder `.py` file in an external terminal, the current console, and Jupyter Notebook and it ran just fine. OP also mentioned that the error stopped occurring with `numba 0.46`.

```sh
(ElM2D) PS C:\Users\sterg> conda list cudatoolkit
# packages in environment at C:\Users\sterg\anaconda3\envs\ElM2D:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               11.2.2               h933977f_8    conda-forge
(ElM2D) PS C:\Users\sterg> conda list numba
# packages in environment at C:\Users\sterg\anaconda3\envs\ElM2D:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numba                     0.55.0.dev0+139.ge050fd691          pypi_0    pypi
```

This is possibly (probably?) because of a [PR](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/6030) mentioned on this [Issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5774). Nonetheless, these access errors still seem to be occurring without necessarily letting you know where (as it did for me), and I was only able to get something more meaningful via **Cuda Simulator**. Hopefully, this can save people from [spending two weeks debugging this particular error](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4783#issuecomment-558103683). If doing this still results in non-descript errors at the `nvvm` level, it may not be a bug in your code but rather an issue that needs to be [opened on Numba GitHub](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new/choose). There are [limitations to using CUDA Simulator](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/simulator.html#supported-features), but I'm glad they have this feature!